# Dynamic programming bottom up approach

Tags: dynamic-programming

Please have a look at this question "Dungeon Princess", https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/dungeon-princess/
I tried to solve it by bottom up approach but got stuck in few cases, can anybody help me out ?
here is my code :

```
 int min(int a, int b)
 {
     return a<b?a:b;
 }
 int max(int a, int b) {
     return a>b?a:b;
 }
int calculateMinimumHP(int** A, int n11, int n12) {
    int arr[n11][n12], i, j, ans=0, minm[n11][n12], t1, t2;
    memset(arr, 0, sizeof(arr));
    memset(minm, 0, sizeof(minm));
    arr[0][0]= A[0][0];
    minm[0][0] = min(ans, A[0][0]);

    for(i=1; i<n11; i++)
    {
        arr[i][0] = arr[i-1][0]+A[i][0];
        minm[i][0]=min(arr[i][0], minm[i-1][0]);
    }
    for(i=1; i<n12; i++)
    {
        arr[0][i] = arr[0][i-1]+A[0][i];
        minm[0][i]=min(arr[0][i], minm[0][i-1]);
    }

    for(i=1; i<n11; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<n12; j++)
        {
            t1 = min(minm[i-1][j], arr[i-1][j]+A[i][j]);
            t2 = min(minm[i][j-1], arr[i][j-1]+A[i][j]);

            if(t1 > t2)
            {
                minm[i][j] = t1;
                arr[i][j] = A[i][j] + arr[i-1][j];
            }
            else
            {
                minm[i][j] = t2;
                arr[i][j] = A[i][j] + arr[i][j-1];
            }

        }
    }

    ans = min(ans, minm[n11-1][n12-1]);
    if(ans == -923)
        return 923;

    return abs(ans)+1;
}
```

Comment: i see that you are only  considering min of two. How about when health increases. When health increase you should use max of.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly what you are doing, you are starting at the top. So it's top-down instead, no?